# How to load all databases in SQL Server, used in C# comboboxs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

My query is when I install this application on some system with SQL Server install I should get all databases in a combobox.

[Login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNVoZ.png)

In the first combobox (Select database type) we have option to select the SQL Server. When I will select the SQL Server, I wish that the available instance of the database like root or something else should come in second combobox. And we should get the database name of the all database in the 3rd combobox

Comment: Mysql or MSSQL? Please correct your post

Comment: yes , i correct it  MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

To list the instances of Sql Server you can use:

```
SQLCMD -L
```

By executing it in a process and collect the output.

For listing of the databases you can use this select statement:

```
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

or

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

The problem is, you need to be logged in to the database to get the list of databases which the logged in user is allowed to see. I think you need to consider it in your application.